# How do I set the height of an html table?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, height

I have read and tried everything that I can find regarding setting  the height of a table, row, etc. in HTML, but none of it works.  I'm trying to make an auto-scrolling marquee with a border, and I have it all working except for the table height.  The text is rather long, so the entire webpage (including the border) scrolls several pages long.  I need to statically set a fixed table/row size to fit onto one single non-scrollable (meaning that I don't want the window to have a scroll bar at all) browser window (say of 800px) which fully contains the border, and then have the very long text auto-scrolling within the border.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>
<style type='text/css'>
html, body {
   background-color: black;
}
table {
   border-spacing: 30px;
   border: 30px;
   border-style: ridge;
}
td {
   padding: 30px;
}
p {
   font-family: calibri;
   color:white;
   font-size: 500%;
   text-align:center;
}
</style>
<body>
<div config-table>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td align ="center">
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="3">
<p>Here I have several paragraphs of text</p>
</marquee>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you define a height to the parent elements ?

Comment: I tried adding it in the style section under html, body, table, th, tr & td, but none of it made any difference.  I tried all of the examples from https://www.w3schools.com/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-the-height-of-rows-in-the-table/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure if this is what you're asking for:

```
<marquee style="border:1px solid red; height:50px;" behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="3">
<p>Here I have several paragraphs of text</p>
</marquee>
```

You can remove the red border.

Let me know if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your suggestion!  I added the height parameter but it didn't work.  It's like most of the parameters aren't valid or something, or else my browser isn't interpreting them correctly.  I had an idea last night which I implemented today (I added an iframe inside of the table border), and I have all of the margin, border and padding setup just the way that I want.  But, the marquee frame still opens super long.  It actually does auto-scroll though I just have to wait about 5 minutes for the text to actually show up in the frame.

Comment: Strange... I literally took your code above and put it into jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) and added the height to the marquee, and it worked.

Comment: Hmm, then it's most like my browser - Brave which is a derivitive of Chrome.  I'll test in a few others and see.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ok, for some reason it works now in Brave!  Here's my final code sections (not complete, just the relavent parts - which some could very well be superfluous):

Comment: Ok, for some reason it works now in Brave!  Here's my final code sections (not complete, just the relevant parts - which some could very well be superfluous):

    <style type='text/css'>
    div {
      width: 1340px;
      height: 650px;
      overflow: auto;
      overflow-style: marquee;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div>
    <marquee style="height:645px;" behavior="scroll" direction="up"     scrollamount="3">
    <p>Here I have several paragraphs of text</p>
    </marquee>
    </div>
    </body>

Comment: Glad you got it working.